# Как дождаться выполнения функции?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

После java асинхронность в js это беда для меня.
Суть проблемы: написать функцию, которая проверяет наличие файла, если есть, то `true`, нет - `false`. Казалось бы все просто, но не тут то было.

Использовал deprecated функцию. И наплодил много кода с ее использованием. Теперь нужно сделать так, чтобы эта же функция работала так же, но была реализована по другому.

Теперь у меня код в `if` выполняется как `false`, не дожидаясь верного ответа от `doesFileExist(urlToFile);` Подскажите пзл, как сюда можно прикрутить ноги? С `$.when` у меня не получается ничего (

```
    function doesFileExist(urlToFile) {
           $.ajax({
               url: urlToFile,
               type: 'HEAD',
               error: function () {
                   console.log(false)
                   return false;
               },
               success: function () {
                   console.log(true)
                   return true;
               }
           });
     }

  if(doesFileExist(url)){}
```

старый вариант

```
      function doesFileExist(urlToFile){
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('HEAD', urlToFile, false);
            xhr.send();
            if (xhr.status == "404") {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Раньше у Вас был синхронный вызов, а теперь стал асинхронный. `return` в `error` и `success` обработчиках - не имеет смысла. Код, который вызывает `doesFileExist`, все равно придется переделывать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Старый вариант - синхронный код (главный поток будет «заморожен»[*](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest) до получения результата). Новый вараинт - асинхронный. И функция `doesFileExist` после отправки асин. запроса будет возвращать `undefined` (так как когда мы ничего не возвращаем (то что в `success` и `error`, выполнится позже, после получения ответа), возвращается `undefined`)

```
doesFileExist() {
    //async action
    setTimeout(function(){ return true; }, 0)

    // return undefined
}
console.log(doesFileExist());  // undefined
```

Чтобы обработать полученный результат, нужно создать функции (в данном случае две), которые будут вызываться при получении ответа.

```
var successCallback = function() { console.log(true); }
var errorCallback = function() { console.log(false); }

doesFileExist(url, successCallback, errorCallback);

function doesFileExist(urlToFile, success, error) {
    $.ajax({
        url: urlToFile,
        error: error,
        success: success
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте 2 новых параметра в функцию `doesFileExist`, например, `successCallback` и `failCallback`. Вместо `return true/false`, выполняйте эти функции: `successCallback()/failCallback()`.

И конечный вызов метода будет примерно такой:

```
doesFileExist(url, function() {
    // файл существует
}, function () {
    // файл отсуствует
});
```